# Xcode - How to delete target in Xcode 6.1?

Tags: xcode6

I cannot find the little box that used to exist in Xcode 5 that would allow me to play/delete targets.

Anyone know how to do this in Xcode 6.1?

Comment: This [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870019/xcode-can-i-delete-test-target/34248001#34248001) post may help.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Just click on the .xcodeproj project file, there you still have the minus signs below the targets and can also right click > Delete

[image]

Comment: @Alan how do you expand the "Show Project and Targets List" pane?  I don't see it in the View menu.  I just have the list of files on the left and the build settings on the right, with no list of targets in the middle!  Now you're driving me crazy :)

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Click on the Project in the left nav pane.  When you do that, there will be a "Show/Hide Project and Targets List" icon just to the right of the Project entry.  In Gerard's photo, it's the blue icon above the word "Project" just to the left of the Red 2.  Hope that helps!

Comment: @Gerard this leaves all the generated sources in my project. I'm assuming I just have to delete those manually?

Comment: @dcow, Yes I believe this does nothing to already generated files, maybe executing a "Clean" helps?