# share Extension IOS 8: How do I remove share itself activity in share category?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-share-extension

Please see the

[image]

As you see, It has a button is share Button. I want to remove it. 
I use share Extension to do share screen shot for my app:

- add target share Extension
- use UIActivityViewController to present.

I able to remove Mail Button, FaceBook button by using this:

```
[activityView setExcludedActivityTypes:@[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypeMail]];
```

but I can't remove the `shareButton` by the way.
Can you help me?

Comment: Is shareButton is your application?

Comment: my app is GamePlay, shareButton is share extension what I add for my app.

Comment: Have u fixed this issue? @Hoc Nguyen Viet. Please provide me the answer if u fixed.

Comment: @karan , I fixed it. I forgot this my topic. :D. The simple to do that : "remove the share Extension target ". Logic to do that: why it appears? It have something to define. And  "the something define" is target. So after create share Extension. work with it. You remove it. It run normally. but don't show anymore. Let me know, if you can't do. I will reproduce by video.

Comment: @HocNguyenViet Do you want me remove the share extension target from project?

Comment: @Karan just only delete target, not remove files

Comment: @HocNguyenViet have you fixed issue?

Comment: I didn't work in IOS a long time. Did you check my previous comments?

Comment: for deleting a target, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324163/xcode-how-to-delete-target-in-xcode-6-1?answertab=votes#tab-top