# Signing for "[AppName]" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, build, react-native

Just started developing a new iOS mobile application with React-Native, running it through XCode. I am attempting to use my personal iPhone as the device I test it on. When I choose "My iPhone" and hit the build button the build fails and I get this error:

`Signing for "[AppName]" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'`

Anyone know how to fix this so I can use my phone instead of the iOS simulators?

Thanks!

Comment: When run on a real device, you need a valid development team, which is a register developer on developer.apple.com. Apple does not allow developer running  anonymous apps on device.

Comment: Hi Mike did you ever find out how to fix this?

Comment: Hi! Yes i did thank you. I had to set the code signing to my development team. I made the development team my personal apple id.

Answer (score 0):

First select your correct Team with correct developer certificates in Build Settings. If you have not any Team certificates then you can not Run project on your device.

Comment: May you please explain this in detail, I am also stuck on this. Do I have to pay and signup on Apple or something?

Comment: I posted my issue here please - http://stackoverflow.com/q/43334982/1828637

Comment: @Noitidart Choose Project -> Build Settings then look for Signing section, select iOS Developer for both Debug and Release rows. Xcode is the worst IDE ever. You likely need to delete all other targets to get build successfully.

Comment: Checking out this link to know how to delete unused targets https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870019/xcode-can-i-delete-test-target

Comment: Thanks very much @TienDo ! You helped me out and I had not even pinged you, thanks very very much! :)

Comment: You're welcome, I faced the same issue yesterday too :)

Comment: Thanks sooo mcuh @TienDo for digging this up and sharing the info. I actually tried in April and gave up haha until you brought me back to trying with your comment. Does this signing section look right to you - http://i.imgur.com/LXLAonb.png - it didn't work so I am going to try to delete other targets now as you mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: @TienDo it worked!!! First I removed **_tvOS and **_tvOS_test then tried but it still failed so I even removed the **_test and build works now!! Thank you sooo much @TienDo!!