# Trying to build to tablet, wanted dev team profile, added one, but now failing for same for "tests"

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am on iOS, creating a react-native iOS app. I was using the simulator but the resolution doesn't look right, its got this black padding etc. So I was trying to test on a device.

I plugged my device in then clicked "Run". It failed under "navi" for reason "Dependency Analysis Error - Signing for "navi" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor. Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'" - screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZKKU.png

So I went to "General" then in signing I clicked "Add Account" then signed in. Then I selected under Team dropdown my thing. Then I tried build again and said I needed a "Unique bundle identifier and to change it", so I added some random numbers then tried again. It popped up asking "Allow acces to keychain" I said "Always Allow". However it is showing me the same exact error as first time, "code signing required", EXCEPT now it is in "naviTests" as seen in screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You choose Target naviTests.
Then you can set signing info.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test this out and get back to you! :)